# Trying to learn basic animation using curve and array modifier and get this to loop

Tags: animation, modifiers

[image][image][image]I am a newbie to Blender who is realizing i need to slow down and learn the basics.  I can use a curve and array modifier to make an object fill up and follow this curve.  I'm assuming there is a way to get this cylinder to appear to be endlessly generating from the origin. Is the only way to do this to set up a procedural animation?  I'm pretty confused and especially confused by the procedural stuff.  thanks.
[image]

Comment: maybe you could use a Boolean modifier to hide the beginning?

Comment: is there a way for me to add another GIF to this discussion.  I think it would help.  thanks

Comment: Do you have some specific issue to add another one gif?

Comment: yes, i think i GIF would help me explain what i'm trying to do so that you smart folks might be able to help me better.

Comment: Thanks.  Now i know i can edit my original question.  And sorry for putting the GIF at the beginning.  you can tell i'm new at this.  What i really want to do is to create the illusion of a continuous flow of something.  That GIF i just posted into the very beginning shows what appears to be a continuous flow.  I am trying to replicate that and do not know how.

Comment: could you please show a drawing of what the final frame would look like? is your shape open? do we see its start and end? is it circular? etc. Also is it just a texture that is moving or is it a 3D object with rings?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by final frame.  I'm guessing that the shape is open.  It is a curve with end that is not back at the beginning.

Comment: could you show a drawing of what the final image should look like? are we supposed to see a start and an end, what is the shape of the curve, etc?

Comment: I added a screen shot from Blender of the curve.

Comment: I am trying to simulate electrical current flow.  I seek to be able to have open ended "wires" with something simulating flow down the wires.

Comment: so this is just a texture along a tube?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer.  I've viewed many tutorials on procedural texturing, animation, etc.  Frankly, i'm a little flummoxed by how to learn blender.  I so solid modeling all the time, but it's challenging to learn where to go next to try to figure this stuff out.

Comment: I suppose the best way to answer is to admit i do not know what a texture along a tube is.

Comment: If you select the curve in edit mode and right click you can choose "Toggle cyclic" then the mesh should cycle back onto itself. If the start and end are clipping you can try to scale it a little bit along the main axis.

Answer (score 0):

Create a cylinder and a curve, give you cylinder an *Array* modifier (with *Merge* option enabled) and a *Curve* modifier, apply the *Array* modifier, unwrap with the *Follow Active Quads* mode, give it a material with *Texture Coordinate (UV output) > Mapping > Wave Texture > ColorRamp > Diffuse > Output*, keyframe the *Mapping* location value to animate the flow:

[image]

file : https://pasteall.org/blend/1fcbf941ca724e03a017d3af9291a4d0

Comment: I will try to figure that out.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: don't hesitate to ask question if you get stuck  ;)

Comment: Moonboots, i've just included a screenshot where i was able to mimic the texture you mention.  I was pretty excited that i was able to accomplish that much.  But i'm not sure how to make the texture move along the curve.  Perhaps I have it moving along the curve and don't realize it, but how in blender do know if it is working?  thanks

Comment: Open the Dope Sheet window, then in your Shader Editor, you need to create a keyframe on the Mapping node's Location value, then a second one a bit further on another frame. If you want the movement to be linear, in the Dope Sheet press T and choose Interpolation > Linear

Comment: actually does your object looks like your first picture? in that case are your kind of rings supposed to move or is it just the texture along the tube?

Comment: Moonboots, i've attached a gif of what it looks like when i run the animation.  This animation I have is not what i'm seeking to do.  I am heartened to hear there is a way to make the texture move along the tube instead of the moving set of objects I currently have in the animation (as shown in the latest gif.  I will need to find time to try to figure out how to follow your directions re the dope sheet.  I had a few minutes and tried but couldn't figure it out.  The texture moving along the curve sounds exactly like what i'm seeking.

Comment: ok so I've edited my answer and shared a file, please check

Comment: Moonboots.  Thanks for the file.  Downloaded it and I think I might be able to duplicate the technique.  But I’ve got a basic problem.  I’m not able to view the procedural animation.  I’m assuming that you call it a procedural animation.

Comment: I have been able to do animations using keyframes actually moving an object and I can view them in the timeline.  But I’m unable to get this procedural animation you did to do anything.  I rendered the animation and it created 100 jpg images in a temp folder on my machine, but I see no movement at all in the rings on the image, so even if I turned those 100 images into a video, I anticipate I would see nothing.

Comment: I wish I had more time to dig into blender.  I’m trying really hard not to give up on it since it is clearly a powerhouse.  Can you tell me how to view what this procedural animation is doing?  Sorry to be “just not getting it”.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to create some keyframes on the Mapping X location value, to create keyframes, open the Dope Sheet window, put your arrow cursor on the location value, press "i", it works. Sure, Blender is a bit hard to understand at the beginning  ;)